# Creating a document (e.g,, MS Word) attachment in Gmail from a spreadsheet script

Tags: gmail, google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs, attachment

I've created a document file in the spreadsheet **script**. What I want to do is, from the script, create an email message with the **document** file (NOT a PDF) as a Gmail attachment. I spent about 2 days looking for a way to do this but with no luck. It must be so easy, I assume, that there's no reason to talk about it! Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Document 'files' are passed as links NOT as attachments in email.
Both Drive and DocsList provide getAs() to give you a PDF but NOT any other mime type.